# How to move a copy of specific files in one folder to another folder based on having the latest "Created date" in Python?

Tags: python, file, shutil

I have a folder that contains about 5,000 files and I need to move the files that start with certain names to another folder. The issue is that I need to only take the file with the most recent created date for that name.

For example:
Let's say one of the names I've been given is "Sam Thompson" and there are three files that meet that criteria...
Sam_Thompson_02012023
Sam_Thompson_02052023
Sam_Thompson_02102023 (let's assume this is the most recently created file)

I need to move only the last file to a different folder as it was created most recently.

I have figured out how to move files based on the name piece but have struggled with finding resources online that relate to my issue very closely.

The below code works perfectly -- it moves the files that start with Sam_Thompson to the appropriate folder. The part that doesn't work is the part that's commented out: and max(file_name, key=os.path.getctime):

I think I'm going about getting the max date by file name incorrectly so any input is appreciated. Most of the material I've looked at online is specific to scenarios where you just want to return the name of the latest file (not move it) and it's typically looking across the whole folder not by each given name.

```
import shutil
import os

source_folder = 'insert path'
destination_folder = 'insert path'
s = 'Sam_Thompson'

for file_name in os.listdir(source_folder):
    source = source_folder + file_name
    destination = destination_folder + file_name
    if os.path.isfile(source) and file_name.startswith(s): #and max(file_name, key=os.path.getctime):
        shutil.copy(source, destination)
        print('Copied:', file_name)
```

Comment: Is the filename consistent, always ending with the underline and a date?

Comment: I simplified it a bit for sake of example, but yes, the file name is always consistent but is something more like Sam_Thompson_XX_XX_02102023

Comment: Do you want to use ctime? Its meaning depends on platform - for linux for example, it would change with a change in owner or access rights. It can also be ambiguous with things like a file copy verses move or move across file system boundaries. Since the name has a timestamp, that may be the better option.

Comment: That timestamp - is it MMDDYYYY or DDMMYYYY?

Comment: @tdelaney I used ctime for another project and I noticed it aligned with the date in the file name 99% of the time, but I hear what you are saying. The date in the file name is usually written as MMDDYY, but since it is manually entered by a user, I was hoping to avoid using that but am open to ideas knowing it wouldn't be perfect.

Comment: Yeah, it can be hard to manage user entered data. On the one hand, they may get the file date wrong, on the other, they may try to "fix" an older file, changing its ctime. If you feel more comfortable with ctime, then stick with it.

Comment: Perhaps you could change the workflow where you have a writable directory but all files are moved into other directories similar to the copy / move you do now. I've written systems using a tools such as inotify where dropping a file into a directory triggers immediate consumption and removal of the file. Just one example...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `file_name` is only looking at one file at a time. You could store the date and then check if subsequent files have a more recent date to find it, but it's easier just to pull all the valid files at once with list comprehension.

```
source_folder = ''
destination_folder = ''
s = ''

valid_files = [file for file in os.listdir(source_folder) if file.startswith(s)]
most_recent = max(valid_files, key = lambda x: os.path.getctime(os.path.abspath(source_folder) + os.sep + x))


source = source_folder + os.sep +  most_recent
destination = destination_folder + os.sep + most_recent

shutil.copy(source, destination)
```

Comment: Thank you. When I try to integrate this into my code, I get this error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: and then it lists one of the files that meet the 's' criteria. I assumed I should be integrating this right after defining 's'. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes, put this right after defining `s`. Do you know what line specifically is raising the error? It shouldn't be coming from these two lines at least.

Comment: It comes back on the line where most_recent is being defined. To attempt to troubleshoot, I removed everything after that and just tried to print most_recent and I get the same error. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I know why. I'm pulling files from the same directory as where the code is run (i.e. my `source_folder` is `'./'`, so I don't need an absolute file path. Let me edit it for a more general solution.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work for me but now when I run the whole program, I am getting no results (even though "most_recent" is returning the appropriate file). Can you review how I implemented it? I think I am off somewhere.        
 for most_recent in os.listdir(source_folder):
    source = source_folder + most_recent
    destination = destination_folder + most_recent
    if os.path.isfile(source):
        shutil.copy(source, destination)
        print('Copied:', most_recent)

Comment: `most_recent` is only a single string with the full path of the filename. If you iterate it, it will just go through each individual character of the string. For clarification, do you only want to move the `most_recent` file or do you want to move all the files that match the filename pattern?

Comment: Oh, that make sense. I am looking to move only the most_recent file. So in my example, that would be Sam_Thompson_02102023.

Comment: @SamanthaThompson Ok, then it's better to store just the filename without the full path. Then you just get the source and destination paths and copy over the file. I've updated the answer accordingly.